# How to make to work openAl in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openal

I have installed openAl in C:/ and followed a lots of tutorials how to make it work. It doesn't recognize al.h, alu.h, alut.h and others components from openAl. I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your project properties, choose `C++ | General`. If your include statements look like:

```
#include "al.h"
```

then be sure to include "C:\openal-soft-1.13\include\AL" in the `Additional Include Directories` section. If your include statements look like:

```
#include "AL/al.h"
```

then be sure to include "C:\openal-soft-1.13\include" in the `Additional Include Directories`’ section.

I'm assuming that your openAL code resides in "C:\openal-soft-1.13". If not, replace that with where it actually resides.